# When querying a TIMESTAMP_LTZ field through application code, snowflake returns the timestamp in UTC instead of the session's timezone

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Account level timezone is America/Los_Angeles.
Session timezone is America/Los_Angeles as well.

But when I query through application code with snowflake-sdk, it's returning the TIMESTAMP_LTZ field in UTC.
However when queried through snowflake UI, it returns in local timezone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does it show if you do the query like ```show parameters like 'TIMEZONE' in session;``` using the different tools (it shows the current timezone applied for the session)

Comment: It says America/Los_Angeles from both UI and application code